# Plot Frequency from Categorical Data over Irregular Intervals in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am hoping someone can help me with the following problem in R, which seems like should have a straightforward answer:

```
#create data frame
df<- data.frame(x = c(1,10,10,40,50,75,100,500,550,600), y = c("black", "black", "red", "black", "blue", "red", "red", "black", "black", "blue"))
 df
 x    y
 1  black
10  black
10  red
40  black
50  blue
75  red
100 red
500 black
550 black
600 blue
 #Where x = days from time 0, y = event
```

How can I graph a time series with frequencies of each variable at regular intervals (e.g. every 30 days) plotted with connecting lines to each point (i.e. not `hist()`)? E.g. for (x, y) would `plot (0-30, black) = 2, (0-60, black) = 1, (60-90, black) = 0`, and so on for each y variable.

I have had success with a different data set using `tally.events()` (epicalc) that works perfectly for what I want using time data but does not work for values that are not 'dates'. Other data set worked as follows:

```
 positive.df 
   resultz    datefix
13       P 2009-02-20
25       P 2009-03-23
45       P 2009-04-27
75       P 2009-07-22
82       P 2009-08-06
94       P 2009-08-19
tally.events(positive.df$datefix, breaks = c("month"), graph = TRUE, line.col ="auto", legend = TRUE, legend.site = "topright")
```

Comment: Plotting frequency: for time point 0-30 (days), black frequency is 2, etc.

Comment: This makes sense? `tapply(df$x, df$y, sum)` or `tapply(df$x, df$y, cumsum)`

Comment: Not quite. Would not like to sum y column, would like to count x variables for each y interval (0-30, 31-60, etc.) and plot. Something like:

Comment: x0to30 <- ftable((subset(df, x <= 30)))
black0to30 <- sum(x0to30[ , 1])

Comment: What about this? `tapply(df$y, as.integer(df$x/30), length)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sq <- seq(0, 600, 30)
x_cut <- cut(df$x, sq)
xt <- xtabs(~ x_cut + y, df)
matplot(xt, col = levels(df$y), type = "o", pch = c(1, 3, 5), xaxt = "n")
axis(1,  seq_along(sq[-1]), sq[-1])
```

which gives:

[image]